# Is there a distinct graph that satisfies this property?

Tags: graph-theory

How many vertices will the following graph have if it contains:

24 edges and all vertices of the same degree.

Let $a=$ Degree of each vertex and $x =$ Number of vertices.

By the handshake lemma you know that

$$2\lvert E \rvert = \sum_{v \in V}deg(v)$$

Using this you know that

$$2\lvert E \rvert = ax$$

Where $E$ is the number of edges.

This mean that

$2(24) = ax$

$48 =ax$

All possible combinations that satisfy this equations are $(1,48), (2,24), (3,16), (4,12), (6,8), (8,6), (12,4), (16,3), (24,2), (48,1)$ where the first entry is the degree of the vertex and the second entry is the number of vertices.

One thing that you need to note is that the degree of a vertex can't be greater than the number of vertices. After looking at that restriction your left with these solutions $(1,48), (2,24), (3,16), (4,12), (6,8)$.

I was wondering is there a unique solution do this question or are all of the answers above legit solutions to the problem? The way the question was worded made it seem like there is a distinct solution but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all legitimate.  $(1, 48)$ is simply 24 matched pairs; $(2, 24)$ is a cycle graph; $(3,16)$ is a cycle graph with the nodes that are 8 edges apart around the cycle connected (so if you label them A-P, you also get AI, BJ, CK...); $(4,12)$ is a cycle graph plus edges between the nodes that are 4 apart (so you get AE, EI, IA, BF, FJ, JB...), and $(6, 8)$ is the complete graph except *without* opposites: it doesn't include AE, BF, CG, or DH.  There are certainly other ways to pull this off, of course, but these are simple enough to envision.